# Why does creating a GTK app cause a dependency error?

Tags: raku

I wanted to test a little `GTK::Simple` app snippet using Perl 6:

```perl
use GTK::Simple;

my GTK::Simple::App $app .= new;
$app.border_width = 20;
$app.set_content(GTK::Simple::Label.new(text => "Goodbye, World!"));
$app.run;
```

<sub>From [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Graphical#Perl_6).</sub>

But I got an interesting error:

```
$ perl6 gui.perl6
===SORRY!===
Failed to open file /home/cat/.perl6/2015.12-221-g85d20f3/precomp/81A1D2D4AD67A53BB9FDD05C0772E081A53D528B.1453913647.88375/D0/D0F2A6FBB788535370F2DE11458DE9A2F602F27A.deps: no such file or directory
```

I `touch`ed that filename, but got a different error instead (so it has to contain something specific, not just a lock):

```
===SORRY!===
Missing or wrong version of dependency '/home/cat/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/sources/D57DE2EF74B56D825F14A3B5B0E6402D49B53D5B' (from '/home/cat/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/site/sources/D0F2A6FBB788535370F2DE11458DE9A2F602F27A')
```

Those filenames contain a bunch of Perl 6 classes and methods, apparently GTK related.

I had installed `GTK::Simple` with `panda install GTK::Simple`, and `panda` claims it was properly installed.

What's happening, and what can I do to fix it?

---

I'm not sure whether this is a bug in Rakudo / Moar, but if it is I don't object to this question's closure.

Comment: Works for me. My guess is your install is broken. Consider reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much but I'm writing this to move things along.

> What's happening?

I know you know this but for those reading along, it's not finding a file it expected to find.

You almost certainly have a broken installation.

> What can I do to fix it?

I suggest you nuke your Rakudo installation (either `rm -rf` or equivalent or `rakudobrew nuke moar`) and reinstall. If that doesn't work [visit #perl6-toolchain](https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.freenode.net/perl6-toolchain), leave a message, and either hang out on the channel for an answer or read the [logs](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6-toolchain/) later.

Here's why I suggest that:

The only interesting results I found by manually checking [a google search of the #perl6 log for 'Failed to open file'](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Airclog.perlgeek.de+inurl%3Aperl6&gws_rd=ssl#q=site:irclog.perlgeek.de+inurl:perl6+%22failed+to+open+file%22&tbas=0) are [a case from December](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2015-12-01#i_11637766) and [a case from January](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-01-03#i_11820810).

In the first case a rebuild fixed the problem according to the log.

In the second case someone who is fairly knowledgeable about the relevant parts of Perl 6 said "time to nuke your install". I didn't find any follow up discussion confirming whether this did or didn't work.

I hope to revisit in a couple days to move things along again if need be.

Comment: @cat Did you accept my answer because you got things working again?

Comment: Latest reply ever, but yes :)

Comment: @cat Thank you. :) ["For those who don't have time: take the time, it's worth it!"](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/4p7bnu/on_the_shoulders_of_giants_damian_conway/d4mhphr) (You won't be disappointed...)

Answer (score 2):

This "just works" (tm) for me.  I'm running `This is Rakudo version 2015.12-232-ga5fe347 built on MoarVM version 2015.12-29-g8079ca5
implementing Perl 6.c.`  Also the module had a slightly more involved example here: [Example 01_hello_world.p6](https://github.com/perl6/gtk-simple/blob/master/examples/01_hello_world.p6) that equally worked verbatim.
The module readme notes;

This modules requires GTK3 library to be installed.

To install it on Debian Linux:

`sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`

I typed exactly that command followed by `panda install GTK::Simple`.  I have no experience with GTK but at first glance  - maybe something wrong with your local install?

If you've installed via **rakudobrew**, it installs in your home directory in `~/.rakudobrew`.  You can relatively painlessly `rm -rf -i ~/.rakudobrew` and start again.  Of course, if this deletes your hard disk and kills your whole family you will have to take responsibility for whatever actions you decide to take ;-).
PS Thankyou for the lead to `GTK:Simple`.  As the name suggests, GTK window applications couldn't be much easier.

Comment: I've got the same version of Rakudo / MVM as you, and I've got `libgtk-3-dev` installed.